# How to correctly search a table based on concatenating 2 table columns in Excel Index/Match Formula

Tags: excel

I'm using Index/Match for a table lookup.  Looking at the expression function arguments, the function seems to calculate correctly, but the cell displays `#VALUE!`  Match finds the correct table index number.
cell formula is:

```
=INDEX(Cards[PN],MATCH([@ProcessorID]&[@CardName],Cards[ProcessorID]&Cards[CardName],0))
```

Below is the formula function arguments:

[image]

Comment: Check this article https://www.excel-easy.com/examples/two-column-lookup.html

Comment: Thanks Ricardo, this helped to explain the array formula issue that I was not aware of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MATCH with concatenated ranges can only function as an array formula, so after editing press `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `Enter`

Comment: Thank you this worked.  I also noticed that my function expression worked w/o the keystroke sequence in Excel Office 365.  This suggestion worked for Excel 2016.

Comment: OK, good to know that. I tested the function with Excel 2013.

Comment: Not all versions in Office 365 have that feature. That was recently released according to this [article](https://office-watch.com/2019/do-you-have-dynamic-arrays-in-excel-365/)